# Vue 3 brakes when building for production using Options API in conjunction with setup script

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I like to use a combination of the `<script setup>` with the options API, and I have encountered a strange issue that has never before happened to me and I've managed to create a new environment to replicate the issue here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-3sc8ha?file=src%2FApp.vue

The file to look at is the App.vue

So basically what happens is that the computed property named "theme" is undefined since the testStore is undefined inside the options API theme getter.

*Important note: It only fails when using "vite build" and it does not happen when using "vite"

If I remove the options API defineComponent script and create the computed property in the setup script as so:

```js
const theme = computed(() => {
    return store.getTheme;
});
```

To summarize the issue:

The defineExpose doesen't seem to be working well when building the vue app for production.

Is this approach of having 2 scripts wrong because I have been working like this since I started using Vue 3 and I haven't had any issues with this until recently.

App.vue Code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    Hi!
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png" />
    {{ theme }}
    <router-view></router-view>
    {{ route.name }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useTestStore } from './stores/test';
import { ref, defineComponent, defineExpose, computed } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
const store = useTestStore();
const test = ref(store.getTheme);
const route = useRoute();

// Using this instead of the options API fixes the problem
// const theme = computed(() => {
//   return store.getTheme;
// });

defineExpose({
  store,
});
</script>

<!-- Commenting the script below fixes the issue -->
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  computed: {
    theme() {
      return this.store.getTheme; //store will be undefined
    },
  },
});
</script>
<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please, provide all relevant code in the question, it needs to be perfectly understandable without navigating to external link. If you have a specific error, it needs to be explicitly listed as well. "Is this approach of having 2 scripts wrong" - yes. You may need `script` with in addition to `script setup` to augment missing component options like name. Things you rely on aren't documented and not guaranteed to work the way you expect them.

Comment: @EstusFlask I see. So in other words, the only real case where I would have both scripts is for the missing options in the setup script.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Normally you won't have a problem like this one.

Comment: @EstusFlask I still think its a bug since it works on development and breaks on build that does not sound like valid behavior but it is what it is.

Comment: Yes, that it's inconsistent suggests that there's a problem at some point (I suspect Vite or Vue compiler), but since it applies to uns
pecified behaviour, I'm not sure it will be qualified as a bug if submitted to issues.

Comment: Yep they did not consider it as a bug :/ @EstusFlask